# Am I approaching this correctly?

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, fxml

JavaFX 8 – FXML – TableView – TableColumn
I have the following objects

```
CourseResult
    SimpleStringProperty CourseID
    SimpleStringProperty CourseName
    SimpleStringProperty Grade
    SimpleIntegerProperty Credits

ATableRow
    SimpleStringProperty StudentID
    SimpleStringProperty StudentName
    CourseResult[]  AResult  // Occurs 1 to 20.
```

In my program

```
javafx.collections.ObservableList<ATableRow> TableData = javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

I populate this Observable list from the database and I am able to see all the values perfectly in debugger.
I create the Tableview and add columns.

```
    public void createTableForThisSemester(int thisSemester, int numberOfCourses, javafx.collections.ObservableList<AResultRow> TableRows) {

        TableView<AResultRow> thisTable = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<AResultRow, String> tcolRollNo = new TableColumn<>("Roll Number");
        tcolRollNo.setEditable(false);
        tcolRollNo.setPrefWidth(120);

        TableColumn<AResultRow, String> tcolName = new TableColumn<>("Student Name");
        tcolName.setEditable(false);
        tcolName.setPrefWidth(350);

        tcolRollNo.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().StudentIDProperty());
        tcolName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().StudentNameProperty());
        boolean xyz = thisTable.getColumns().addAll(tcolRollNo, tcolName);

 //       TableColumn[] courseColumn = new TableColumn[numberOfCourses];

        for (int courseNo = 0; courseNo < numberOfCourses; courseNo++) {
            String colName = getASemesterCourse(thisSemester, courseNo).getCourseID();
            TableColumn<AResultRow, String> thisColumn = new TableColumn<>(colName);
            thisColumn.setPrefWidth(80);
            thisColumn.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER; font-weight:bold;");

thisColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().courseGradeProperty(courseNo));

            boolean retVal = thisTable.getColumns().addAll(thisColumn);
        }
//        System.out.println("# of Rows in Table [" + thisSemester + "] = " + TableRows.size());

        thisTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        thisTable.setItems(TableRows);

        ScrollPane thisScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        thisScrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
        thisScrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        thisScrollPane.setMinHeight((theDetails.getHeight() - 25));
        thisScrollPane.setMaxHeight((theDetails.getHeight() - 25));
        thisScrollPane.setMinWidth((theDetails.getWidth() - 25));
        thisScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        Tab thisTab = tabs.getTabs().get(thisSemester);
        thisTab.setContent(thisScrollPane);

        thisScrollPane.setContent(thisTable);
    }
```

Columns StudentID and Name are perfectly populated. But the Results are not being populated in

thisColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().courseGradeProperty(courseNo));

I get this error in Netbeans for the line shown above. "Local Variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final".

Remember, the GRADE[courseNo] field is a String and is populated.

How to show this value in the TABLE.

I have been trying various methods, like storing this value in a temp String... etc. etc.

Comment: The error refers to `courseNo`. You can try introducing a new variable inside the scope of the `for` loop. Such a variable will be effectively final in it's scope (or you can explicitly define it as final). Something like `final int number = courseNo;` as the first line of the loop should work, then use `number` instead of `courseNo`.

Comment: Thanks Sillyfly.............This worked. I was struggling with the Grade field. I did not even suspect that the index is the one which has to be final. Thanks, Thanks, Thanks.......

Comment: Hi Sillyfly, this is continuation to the above problem. I want to set the Tooltip for each cell. The text for the Tooltip is in the class CourseResult (not shown in my example). There is a method called getTooltip in CourseResult which returns a String explaining the Cell content.

Comment: Oops.... sorry. I need to get the String and set this value as thisColumn.setTooltip(returnedString); Remeber, that the ROW in the table is class TableRows and has an array of CourseResult. But I know that correct index for the CourseResult array. How do I retrieve this Tooltip. I want the GRADE[courseNo] is what is displayed in the cell and the Tooltip string is different. How do I acheive this ?